# Генерация результатов на дату из интервала

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеются три таблицы, где описаны кураторы (master), события (event) и привязка кураторов и событий (masterOfEvent). Поля с датами, то есть start и stop, как в событии так и в привязке означают с какого по какое число шло событие, и с какого по какое число событие вел тот или иной куратор. Необходимо вывести не данные с какого по какое и кто вел, а на каждый день начиная с начала года ведущих событий.

```
master (
    id int,
    name varchar,
)

event (
    id int,
    start date,
    stop date
)


masterOfEvent (
    master_id,
    event_id,
    start date,
    stop date
)
```

То есть, если событие шло с 01.01.2019 по 25.01.2019, и было три куратора  John 01.01.2019 по 09.01.2019, Mike 10.01.2019 по 17.01.2019, Bob 18.01.2019 по 25.01.2019, результирующие строки должны быть примерно такие:

```
concert 01.01.2019 John
concert 02.01.2019 John
concert 03.01.2019 John
concert 04.01.2019 John
concert 05.01.2019 John
concert 06.01.2019 John
concert 07.01.2019 John
concert 08.01.2019 John
concert 09.01.2019 John
concert 10.01.2019 Mike 
concert 11.01.2019 Mike 
concert 12.01.2019 Mike 
concert 13.01.2019 Mike 
concert 14.01.2019 Mike 
concert 15.01.2019 Mike 
concert 16.01.2019 Mike 
concert 17.01.2019 Mike 
concert 18.01.2019 Bob 
concert 19.01.2019 Bob  
concert 20.01.2019 Bob 
concert 21.01.2019 Bob 
concert 22.01.2019 Bob 
concert 23.01.2019 Bob 
concert 24.01.2019 Bob 
concert 25.01.2019 Bob
```

[ЗДЕСЬ НЕБОЛЬШОЙ ПРИМЕР](http://rextester.com/EBVSZA45522)

Comment: сгенерите таблицу с последовательными датами и приджойните вашиданные

Comment: Соединение осуществлять по какому полю ? Я так сделал, но "пустые даты" пропустились..

Comment: А в схеме имеется констрейнт, который гарантирует не-перекрытие диапазонов в masterOfEvent? если нет - то что должно выводиться, если на какую-то дату попадают сразу два куратора?

Comment: *Соединение осуществлять по какому полю ?* `WHERE generated_date BETWEEN masterOfEvent.start AND masterOfEvent.stop`, есссно. Плюс условие по event_id. *"пустые даты" пропустились..* Покажите в примере вывода такие "пустые даты".

Comment: _пропустились_ в смысле остались? левый джойн сделали что ли?

Comment: Перекрытий быть не должно, максимум null в дате завершения. Припустились потому что соединение было по дате start. Что значит поле generated_date в вашем предикате ?

Comment: поле даты из сгенерированой таблицы дат

Comment: А как вы предлагаете в запросе таблицу дат и таблицу masterOfEvent связать через предикат и выборку из двух таблиц через запятую ?

Comment: Вот сделал небольшой пример - https://rextester.com/EBVSZA45522

Comment: у вас там таблица `@master` по ключу `event_id` джойнится. зы: зачем `datetime` если речь про `date`, и всякие конверты отсюда? каст к дате на край

Comment: Как говорится глаз замылился и опечатался, конечно по master_id, спасибо. А datetime или date разницы особой нет, как и как конверить, имхо..

Comment: если date, то значения просто подставляются без всяких конвертов. очевидно, такое сравнение будет работать быстрее и использовать индексы при возможности. конверты здесь просто излишни

Comment: Это да, но если в таблице start и stop datetime, то увы.. Это всего лишь пример был, спасибо что помогли)

Comment: если datetime то все равно обычное сравнение быстрее, чем конвертить в строки и сравнивать их